# using Google cloud endpoint framework 2.0 with custom domain

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2, custom-domain

Im hosting a mobile backend (written in Java) in `App engine standard environment` using `Cloud endpoint framework 2.0`, which I can access by this URL  https://api-dot-[projectId]-appspot.com/_ah/api/myApi/v1/path

now Im trying to use a custom domain [api.mydomain.app] and here what I've done:

1- I've added this domain `api.mydomain.app` in my appengine setting and its now verified and has a valid SSL managed by google

2- I've added the 8 DNS records (A & AAAA) in this domain "mydomain.app" in godaddy like below:

```
A   api xxxxxxx
A   api xxxxxxx
A   api xxxxxxx
A   api xxxxxxx

AAAA    api xxxxxxx
AAAA    api xxxxxxx
AAAA    api xxxxxxx
AAAA    api xxxxxxx
```

and I have the same records for `@` (for the default service) and `admin` (for the admin service) and both are working just fine 
I have also this record `CNAME  *   ghs.googlehosted.com`

3- I've added these records below in the dispatch.xml:

```
  <dispatch>
       <!-- Send all Mobile traffic to the API. -->
      <url>api.mydomain.app/*</url>     
      <module>api</module>
  </dispatch>   

 <dispatch>
      <!-- Send all Admin traffic to the Admin Platform. -->
      <url>admin.harmonica.app/*</url>
      <module>admin</module>
  </dispatch>
```

4- the module name for this backend is defined in `appengine-web.xml` as `api`

5- this is the definition of my API class

```
@Api(name = "myApi", version = "v1", authenticators = { Authenticator.class },
        // scopes = { Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE },
        clientIds = { Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
                Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID }, description = "API for Harmonica Backend application.")
public class MyApi {...}
```

6- this is how I define the EndpointsServlet in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

so after doing all of that whenever I try to access `https://api.mydomain.app/myApi/v1/path` or `https://api.mydomain.app/path` 
it shows me this response:

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /dating was not found on this server.
```

and in the server logs I see this `No handlers matched this URL.`

So can you plz help me out? did I miss out anything ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Screenshots of the exact responses and server logs when they appear would be helpful.

Comment: I edited my question by including this info

Comment: @saiyr so any input from ur side? any info that I miss?

Comment: Can you include the part of `web.xml` that configures `EndpointsServlet`?

Comment: @saiyr done! ...

Comment: It seems you should be trying `https://api.mydomain.app/_ah/api/myApi/v1/path`, not `httpss://api.mydomain.app/myApi/v1/path`.

Comment: yeah I tried to send a request on that format too, but it shows me "Error: Not Found" in the response and I cant even find this request in the server logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171183/discussion-between-saiyr-and-tamer-saleh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the url-pattern of EndpointsServlet to be:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <!--   This is for accessing the API by the domain name -->
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    <!--   This is for the backward compatibility -->
      <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

and now I can access my API from my custom domain.